# Content inside iframe is invisible at IOS (Iphone & IPAD)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, iframe

Hello following iframe code is not getting displayed at iPhone at all. It loads fine on other browsers and Android mobile browser. On Safari desktop browser, I need to specify
iframe onload=iFrameHeight(700) to make it displayed. However this still does not help for iPhone.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

```html
<div class="contentpane"> <iframe onload="iFrameHeight()" id="blockrandom" name="iframe" src="http://www.maxhire.net/cp/?E5586A361E43515B79561C6532531A2604" width="100%" height="700" scrolling="no" align="top" frameborder="0" class="wrapper"> This option will not work correctly. Unfortunately, your browser does not support inline frames.</iframe> </div>
```